# What is difference between inflating layout with false attachtoroot and true attachtoroot(boolean)

Tags: android, android-layout, view

What is difference between inflating layout with false attachtoroot and true attachtoroot(boolean)?

Here is a code:

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_screen_3, container, false);
```

and:

```
ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_screen_3, container, true);
```

Answer (score 5):

The `root` and `attachToRoot` parameters work together.

If you tell `inflate()` to attach the inflated View to the root View, then the layout that you inflate will be added as a child to the root.

Here is a simplification of what the `inflate()` method does:

```
public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot) {
    View inflatedView = inflate(resource); // Inflate the desired view

    if (attachToRoot) {
        root.addView(inflatedView);
    }
}
```

This is useful if you are inflating Views that are going to be attached to a parent view eventually anyway, for example if you are inflating a number of Views with the same layout to dynamically populate a ListView.

Answer (score 3):

When `attachToRoot` = false :
- the returned `rootView` will be the top `ViewGroup` from `R.layout.fragment_screen_3` and `rootView` still doesn't add into `container` yet.(Can be added to another view group parent)
- It'll raise an Exception if the top tag in `R.layout.fragment_screen_3` is `<merge>`.

When `attachToRoot` = true :
- the return `rootView` will be the `container`.
- the content of `R.layout.fragment_screen_3` will be added as a part of `container` (like when you use `attachToRoot` = false, then call `container.addView(rootView);`
- can use with `<merge>` tag in `R.layout.fragment_screen_3`

Answer (score 1):

## When to use which?

- Use `attachToRoot = true` when you want to add the childView to
  parent **right now**.
- Use `attachToRoot = false`  when you want to add the childView to parent
  at **later** point.

> You should also use `attachToRoot = false` When you are not
>   responsible for adding the childView.

Eg. While adding Fragments

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent,Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater,parent,bundle);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment,parent,false);
    .....
    return view;
}
```

If you pass third parameter as true you will get IllegalStateException because of this guy.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .add(parent, childFragment)
  .commit();
```

Since you have already added the child fragment in onCreateView() by mistake. Calling `add(parent, childFragment)` will throw IllegalStateException because the child view was already added.
Here you are not responsible for adding childView, FragmentManager is responsible. So always pass false in this case.